# Is ClearType enabled here?

Tags: fonts, cleartype, pspad

I'm using PSPad as a code editor but I'm not sure whether ClearType is enabled. Although one may say that if I see no difference that I shouldn't make a point of it, but I'm just curious to know.

I'm using the Consolas font (which is said to be optimized for ClearType).

If I disable/enable ClearType on Windows, I do see difference everywhere on Windows (menus etc), except in the code editor. So either ClearType is not enabled within the code editor at all, or Consolas is always using ClearType. I do not know.

Hopefully this image clearifies it (is this drawn using ClearType?):
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it to me.

Comment: It's looks as though ClearType is in effect, as can be seen in this [blowup](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5508445/superuser/i.imgur.com_6Y3AX%20magnified.png) of your image.

Comment: "So either ClearType is not enabled within the code editor at all, or Consolas is always using ClearType" – Programs can override the system-wide font smoothing option for their own windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Consolidating comments in to an answer:</sub>

---

> So either ClearType is not enabled within the code editor at all, or Consolas is always using ClearType. I do not know.

Programs can override the system-wide font smoothing option for their own windows, so it is quite possible that the editor is using ClearType for it's own windows independently of your system settings.

And, it looks as though ClearType *is* in effect, as you can see the smoothing on letters in this enlargement of your image:

[image: enlarged section of screenshot in question, showing smoothing on letters]